# How to create an uber-jar with external resource configuration

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to create uberjar, which will contain the java-dependencies and the configuration directory will be located out of the jar?
any ideas?

The structure should be something like this:

MyOutputDir 
|
 ----- MyApp(jar-with-dependencies) 
 ----- conf

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to include dependencies, try using the maven shade plugin within the plugins node. Simply include the artifacts that you want added to your shaded jar.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
```

More info at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/